# How to setup SFTP in XAMPP with php version 7.0.14

Tags: php, xampp

I use XAMPP 3.2.2 with PHP version 7.0.14.

I need to upgrade my connection from ftp to sftp. Currently I'm trying below connection.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('server.com');

$tmp_dir = "\test\path\";    

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password');    
ftp_chdir($conn_id, "path/$id"); 
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
$i = 0;
$files_to_zip = array();
sort($contents);
foreach($contents as $filename) {
    if($_GET['file'.$i] == 'file'.$i++) { 
        $handle = fopen("/$filename", "w");
        $get = ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $filename, FTP_BINARY);  
        fclose($handle);   
        $files_to_zip[$filename] = $tmp_dir . "/$filename"; 
    }
} 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

How do I move to sftp connection?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried ssh2 however could not find install for PHP 7.0.14. Is there an alternative?